# Need to compare a variable to an array

Tags: javascript, arrays

I have these two arrays;

```
theImages1 = new Array();
    theImages1[0] = 'images/1-0000-0400-0487-3.6-0.9.gif'
    theImages1[1] = 'images/1-0000-0450-0526-3.2-0.8.gif'
    theImages1[2] = 'images/1-0000-0500-0568-2.9-0.7.gif'
theImages2 = new Array();
    theImages2[0] = ['images/1-0000-0400-0487-3.6-0.9.gif', 100000.5]
    theImages2[1] = ['images/1-0000-0450-0526-3.2-0.8.gif', 200000.6]
    theImages2[2] = ['images/1-0000-0500-0568-2.9-0.7.gif', 300000.7]
```

theImages1 is displayed randomly on a timer as the variable imageDisplay.

I need to compare imageDisplay to theImages2 and if they match I need to retrieve the value of the second part of theImages2 which is the long number to the right in the array

Example 300000.7

I have been trying to complete the comparison using a loop and if statement as follows...

```
canoe = imageDisplay
for (i=0; i<theImages11.length; i++) {
    if (canoe == theImages11[i]) {
        alert("yes")
    }
    else {
        alert("no")
    }
}
```

However, because of the second part of theImages2 array the alert is always "no". I also have no idea of how to go about retrieving the second part of the array which is the number.
Thanks for any feedback.

Comment: I assume `theImages11` is basically `theImages2`. in that case instead of `theImages11[i]`, it should be `theImages11[i][0]`. And it should work.

Answer (score 0):

Given your initial data:

```
theImages1 = new Array();
theImages1[0] = 'images/1-0000-0400-0487-3.6-0.9.gif'
theImages1[1] = 'images/1-0000-0450-0526-3.2-0.8.gif'
theImages1[2] = 'images/1-0000-0500-0568-2.9-0.7.gif'

theImages2 = new Array();
theImages2[0] = ['images/1-0000-0400-0487-3.6-0.9.gif', 100000.5]
theImages2[1] = ['images/1-0000-0450-0526-3.2-0.8.gif', 200000.6]
theImages2[2] = ['images/1-0000-0500-0568-2.9-0.7.gif', 300000.7]
```

You just need a better understanding of the array indexing that you are using:

```
canoe = imageDisplay // e.g., images/1-0000-0500-0568-2.9-0.7.gif

for (i=0; i<theImages2.length; i++) {
    if (canoe == theImages2[i][0]) // first index pos of each entry
        return theImages2[i][1]; // return the 2nd index pos (the value)
    }
}
return false; // no match, return false or whatever other failure
```